# cannot import name 'convert_to_utm' from 'coordinates'

Tags: python

---

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
11 from coordinates import Coordinate
12
---> 13 from coordinates import convert_to_utm

ImportError: cannot import name 'convert_to_utm' from 'coordinates' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/coordinates/**init**.py)
[eror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IZkK.png)

Comment: It says that there is no function (or rather, no object - a function is just an object, but so is everything else) called `convert_to_utm` in the `coordinates` module - where did you read that there is ?

Comment: Use `import coordinates` and `dir(coordinates)` from an interactive prompt. For a proper question here, this needs a [mcve]. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].